# Docker image name from sha256 /digest

Tags: image, docker, containers, repository, sha256

Is there a way to get the docker image name if I have the corresponding sha256 code /digest for it?

Just to elaborate, when we perform docker image inspect ImageName
it gives a list of layers in the form of sha256 codes.
Can we trace the imageNames for the underlying layers?

Any help would highly be appreciated.